# Dynamic class change not recognised by jquery when submitting form

Tags: jquery, forms, addclass

I have an anchor tag with class ".disable" and script that toggles it to ".enable".

```
if((counter.text() < 140) && (counter.text() >= 0)) {
  $('#tweet').addClass("enable");
  $('#tweet').removeClass("disable");
} else {
  $('#tweet').addClass("disable");
  $('#tweet').removeClass("enable");
}
```

The anchor is used to submit a form but only when the class is set to ".enable".

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $(".enable").click( function(e){
    (e).preventDefault();
    $("#myform").submit();
  });
});
```

Howver, this doesn't work. The second script doesn't seem to recognise the dynamic .class change. If I change the class in the above code to ".disable", it works.

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you please flick some html? might take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $("#tweet").click( function(e){
    (e).preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("enable")) {
       $("#myform").submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Great. :) That works. I'm going with this solution for now. If it is better practice to use MC10s solution, I may use that later. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is failing to work properly is because your code attaches an event **only** to elements that have the class `enable` at page load, which is likely none. Thus, no event handlers would ever be attached, and your code would never run. In order for your handlers to update with your class additions/removals, you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (if you're using jQuery 1.7+) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (if you're using jQuery older than 1.7):

To use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".enable", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myform").submit();
    });
});
```

To use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$(function() {
    $("body").delegate(".enable", "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myform").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for the explanation. However, I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and the above on() doesn't work. Never-the-less, is it advisable to always use on()? Should I be converting all my jQuery events where applicable?